# Add User to default User Group

Tags: winforms, powershell

I want to create a user and add it to the standard user group.

How can I do this?

Code:

```
$button_BenutzerErstellen_OnClick = {
    $textBox6.Text
    # Define password variable as SecureString
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString $textBox7.Text -AsPlainText -Force

    # Check for empty Textboxes
    if (($handler_textBox6.Text -eq 0) -or ($handler_textBox7.TextLength -eq 0)) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Bitte füllen Sie alle Kriterien aus.", "Combat 19")
    } else {
        # create user
        New-LocalUser $textBox6.Text -Password $password -Description $textBox1
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Benutzer wurde erstellt!", "Combat 19")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc,  What have you tried when it comes to creating a user?

Comment: I can create a user, but i cant login right after i created it. So the User needs to be in the default user group. I want to move the new user in the group.

Comment: There is usually some replication time from when you create a user to when you can login as them, can be up to 15 minutes for the DC to sync again

Comment: @LachieWhite Apparently the script is [supposed to create local users](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41922771/1630171), so no replication involved. However, my question still stands: what's wrong with using `lusrmgr.msc` instead of trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: ahh sorry thought you referring to AD Users!

Comment: @MarcHofstetter: If the issue has been resolved . Could you please mark it as accepted else people will keep on adding answer thinking its not done.

Comment: @RanadipDutta An accepted answer will not prevent people from adding answers, at least not those who know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how creation of user is linked with the script you have highlighted. 
I believe you are talking about local users and groups.

Then you can use:

**For USers**

```
NET USER username "password" /ADD
```

**For Adding it to Group**

```
NET LOCALGROUP "group" "user" /add
```

Comment: @MarcHofstetter: Accept the answer if it helps you